# OAuth2 retrieve client_id in CustomUserDetailsService

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I created a Spring Boot application configured to be my Authorization Server oauth2, have other applications Spring boot that are configured as Client oauth2.

In my server I implemented CustomUserDetailsService I would like in the method loadUserByUsername to retrieve the client_id of the project that is being authenticated.

I do not know if this is possible, but I would like to recover this to validate the client_id because I have several applications that use the same authorizer and by client_id I will check if the user has access to that application.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**application.yml**  client

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    sso:
      loginPath: /login
    client:
      clientId: web_app
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: https://localhost/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://localhost/uaa/oauth/authorize
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {

            //I would like to recover the client_id in this location

            User domainUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
```

Have to validate any server because I have a single login for all applications:

Auth server authentication is done by user and password and application.

Imagine that you are logging into "https://accounts.google.com/" google checks user and password and displays your account with shortcuts to "PRODUCTS".

Now if you access "https://mail.google.com" google checks user and password and displays the gmail interface. In my case it can come from the URL https://application.domain.com, https://application2.domain.com, https://application3.domain.com or "https://accounts.domain.com.

All URLs it uses user and password, but it can have access to application1 or all or none.

I would like to do the server side, because it returns the access token only for applications that have permission (credit). If the user and password are correct it does not mean that the user has access to all the applications.

Answer (score 1):

```
final SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
if (null != savedRequest) {
    final String redirectUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
    final MultiValueMap parameters = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(redirectUrl).build().getQueryParams();
    if (parameters.containsKey("client_id")) {
        final String clientId = parameters.get("client_id").get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the client_id you need to Implement a different interface. The `CustomUserDetailsService` will only give you access to User object.

I don't the exact way to do this in `Spring Boot` but, in XML-based configuration you will have to do something as follow

```
public class CustomJdbcClientDetailsService implements 
       ClientDetailsService, ClientRegistrationService {

       @Override
       public CustomClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId)
              throws InvalidClientException {
           //Do something with clientId 
       }
}
```

In short the method `loadClientByClientId` gives you access to the client id. There are other ways that you could intercept different Spring OAuth2 classes and access the `client_id` but, this is the cleanest and recommended approach.

You might also be able to access the `client_id` by adding a `Filter` to intercept the request and check the body.

You need to do some research on how to implement `ClientDetailsService` and `ClientRegistrationService` in `Spring Boot`. There gotta be a ton of tutorials about it.

It's best to start with Googling how to setup `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` with `Spring Boot`

1. For more on `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` See [Spring OAuth Java Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/configurers/ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.html)
2. [A good tutorial](https://jugbd.org/2017/09/19/implementing-oauth2-spring-boot-spring-security/) and [this one](https://dazito.com/java/spring-boot-and-oauth2-with-jdbc)